# Display Images from file into datagridview depending on model name

Tags: sql, vb.net, image, datagridview

Hi so for this part of my program it's basically a gallery for origami artists to view existing crease patterns designed by other artists. I have the program showing the Artist name, difficulty, theme and model name but I also want it to display the image of the crease pattern of the specific origami model in the datagridview. I have all the images are saved on my laptop and I have searched around a lot but haven't found a solution. I've tried the Datagridviewimage column but it came up with an error as well as the Datagridview cell formatting. [Here is a pic of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGYKH.jpg)

Here is my code:

Public Class Gallery
    Dim SQl As New SQLControl

```
Private Sub Gallery_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    LoadGrid()
    GetArtists()
    GetDifficulties()
    GetTheme()

End Sub
Private Sub LoadGrid()
    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT ArtistName, Difficulty, Theme, ModelName, CreasePattern " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "ORDER BY ArtistName ASC, ModelName ASC ")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then GalleryResult.DataSource = SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0)

End Sub

Private Sub ModelSearch(ModelName As String)
    SQl.AddParam("@ModelName", "%" & ModelName & "%")

    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT ArtistName, Difficulty, Theme, ModelName, CreasePattern " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "WHERE ModelName LIKE @ModelName " &
                  "ORDER BY ArtistName ASC, ModelName ASC ")

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then MsgBox(SQl.Exception) : Exit Sub

    GalleryResult.DataSource = SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0)
End Sub
Private Sub ArtistSearch(ArtistName As String)
    SQl.AddParam("@ArtistName", "%" & ArtistName & "%")

    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT ArtistName, Difficulty, Theme, ModelName, CreasePattern " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "WHERE ArtistName LIKE @ArtistName " &
                  "ORDER BY ArtistName ASC, ModelName ASC ")

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then MsgBox(SQl.Exception) : Exit Sub

    GalleryResult.DataSource = SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0)
End Sub
Private Sub DifficultySearch(Difficulty As String)
    SQl.AddParam("@Difficulty", "%" & Difficulty & "%")

    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT ArtistName, Difficulty, Theme, ModelName, CreasePattern " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "WHERE Difficulty LIKE @Difficulty " &
                  "ORDER BY ArtistName ASC, ModelName ASC ")

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then MsgBox(SQl.Exception) : Exit Sub

    GalleryResult.DataSource = SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0)
End Sub
Private Sub ThemeSearch(Theme As String)
    SQl.AddParam("@Theme", "%" & Theme & "%")

    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT ArtistName, Difficulty, Theme, ModelName, CreasePattern " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "WHERE Theme LIKE @Theme " &
                  "ORDER BY ArtistName ASC, ModelName ASC ")

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then MsgBox(SQl.Exception) : Exit Sub

    GalleryResult.DataSource = SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0)
End Sub
Private Sub SearchBt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchBt.Click
    ModelSearch(ModelNameTxt.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub ArtistNameBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ArtistNameBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    ArtistSearch(ArtistNameBox.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub DifficultyBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DifficultyBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    DifficultySearch(DifficultyBox.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub ThemeBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ThemeBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    ThemeSearch(ThemeBox.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub GetArtists()
    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ArtistName " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "ORDER BY ArtistName ASC ")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
            ArtistNameBox.Items.Add(dr("ArtistName").ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub GetDifficulties()
    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Difficulty " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "ORDER BY Difficulty ASC ")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
            DifficultyBox.Items.Add(dr("Difficulty").ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub GetTheme()
    SQl.ExecQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Theme " &
                  "FROM GalleryTB " &
                  "ORDER BY Theme ASC ")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQl.Exception) Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In SQl.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
            ThemeBox.Items.Add(dr("Theme").ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub BackToMainmenuBT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackToMainmenuBT.Click
    Me.Close()
    Mainmenu.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub GalleryResult_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles GalleryResult.CellFormatting
    If GalleryResult.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Link = GalleryResult.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value
        If Link.ToString.Contains("Ryujin 3.5") Then
            GalleryResult.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Suraj_2\Downloads\Pictures\Origami\Ryujin 3.5 CP.jpg")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class SQLControl
    'Private SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\Projects;Database=GalleryDB"}
    Private SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=GalleryDB"}
    Private SQlCmd As SqlCommand

```
Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
Public SQLDS As DataSet

Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

Public RecordCount As Integer
Public Exception As String

Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()

        SQlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) SQlCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()

        SQLDS = New DataSet
        SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQlCmd)
        RecordCount = SQLDA.Fill(SQLDS)


        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLCon.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub
```

End Class
Edit***
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc5DZ.jpg)
[Table][3]

Thanks,
   Mistry27

Comment: Can you show us the error you got?

Comment: I haven't worked with images in a database before so bar the research it is new to me